# Tesseract crash on Release build, Debug build works fine

Tags: c++, qt, tesseract

I am developing tesseract based application in Qt creator, and I noticed that my application crashes on release mode where as the debug version works without any problem. And I found out the problem happening at "TessBaseAPI class initialization". The crash occurs only if I declare "TessBaseAPI as a pointer".

That is, the below line of code crash on release mode, but works on debug mode

```
 TessBaseAPI *tesseract;
 tesseract=new TessBaseAPI();
 tesseract->Init("./Resources/data/ocr", "lus",tesseract::OEM_DEFAULT);
```

Where as the below works fine

```
TessBaseAPI tesseract;
tesseract.Init("./Resources/data/ocr", "lus",tesseract::OEM_DEFAULT);
```

I am running Qt creator 5.4 MSVC2013 on Windows 8. The tesseract library is build according the instruction from [here](http://vorba.ch/2014/tesseract-3.03-vs2013.html). And I am linking tesseract library statically.

Here is my .pro file

```
LIBS += -L./tesseract/lib \
   -lliblept171 \
   -lWs2_32 \
   -llibtesseract304-static
```

Any one know what can be the issue here, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Does the debug-build run fine when running in a debugger, or when running outside a debugger as well?

Comment: Yes both case it running fine.

Comment: If it works in Debug but crashes in Release, the point where it crashes is usually far away from the actual problem. The usual culprits are uninitialized variables or buffer overruns somewhere else in your code.

Comment: Yes I read few post about it, and I was trying to figure where it happening, now found some tesseract code creates problem.